# Do I need an API route for a home page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I understand that people use something like `"/api"` to send data. but lets say I have a page that has a route ("/home") I could do DB stuff and send a res.send() with the data from the DB. Should I be making a call to the /api when the user visits the home page? Why would I need both? I see people talking about api routes but I'm not sure when to use it. I'm assuming we don't do `res.render` in an `/api` route. It is mostly to send `JSON`. I never use api route I usually use the /home way. Should I be using the `api` way?

I'm confused on when to use it

Edit I guess a use case for having both is returning data for outside users and to also returning data for your website. Do people combine both?

Answer (score 0):

It is just about naming convention. `/api` is where people keep APIs for single pages apps or mobile apps. If you have neither of those, you can use `/home` or for that matter, any named route for your purpose. It is just a coding practice and nothing else.